# TSQL Join performance on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, join

I have a join performance problem that has proven tougher to crack than expected.

```
SELECT distinct
             tx.[Counter],
             tx.[time],
             tx.[Count] PassengerProcessed,
             tx.Wait,
             tx.[Length] QueueLength,
             tx.DW_SK_WaitingTime,
             tx.QueueId,
             bc.AIRLINE
      FROM stg.TmpCheckInStep1  tx
           LEFT JOIN DSO_WaitingTime.stg.TmpBagCounter bc ON tx.[Counter] = bc.COUNTER_ID
           AND tx.[time] >= bc.ROLLED_ON_TM_UTC
           AND tx.[time] < bc.ROLLED_OFF_TM_UTC
```

The tx table is about 20 million rows, the BC table is approx 1 million.
The current runtime is at least a couple of hours.

Both tables is a part of a workflow where they are dropped and recreated each night.

BC has a nonclusted index on `Counter_ID` with `Airlined`, `ROLLED_ON_TM_UTC`, `ROLLED_OFF_TM_UTC` included.

TX currently has a nonclusted index on Counter, not including Time. I have tried to include Time in the index, but to no avail.

The current Execution plan looks as follows:
[ExecutionPlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZGyR.png)

I'm guessing its the greater than, less than condition that ruins the performance.
How can I improve either the query or the indexes in order to speed this up?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the suggestions so far - I'm just in the process of testing the clustered index suggested by Dan Guzman. Without the DISTINCT the execution time is drastically reduced. The execution plan changes to be 100% on the index seek: brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ6i5YcMf

Comment: How much time does it take if you remove the `distinct`?

Comment: I'd personally try a new index specifically on bc.counter_id, bc.ROLLED_ON_TM_UTC, bc.ROLLED_OFF_TM_UTC and include bc.AIRLINE

Comment: Try a clustered index on tx(COUNTER_ID, TIME). Upload execution plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ rather than pasting images.

Comment: The largest chuck is a hash match, which I'm pretty sure is your join.  I think this means that your index on BC is too complicated; you might try adding a nonclustered index on JUST Counter_ID; the composite indexes might not be affecting performance the way you want.

Comment: @DylanB - the hash match is to remove duplicates for the DISTINCT. Despite this showing up as a high cost I imagine that it is 20 million seeks with residual predicates that is really the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far - I'm just in the process of testing the clustered index suggested by Dan Guzman. Without the DISTINCT the execution time is drastically reduced. The execution plan changes to be 100% on the index seek: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ6i5YcMf

Comment: @Torstein you may want to edit that link into your question incase people aren't going to dive into the comments